# In Imagick (PHP), how can i negate without changing the alpha (transparent)?

Tags: php, imagick

In Imagick, when i use "negateImage" in images with alpha channel (png), the transparency is not well handled by imagick. I want to keep the transparency, only negate the "colored" pixels.

[Origin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ae3.png)

[Desired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydZGN.png)

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the specific channels that you want to negate:

```
$imagick->negateImage(false, imagick::CHANNEL_RED | imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN | imagick::CHANNEL_BLUE);
```

The above assumes an RGB image.